# Extending margins on larger Screens

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Is there a way in android to make the margins extend to fill screens? The problem is that layouts I build for Nexus devices look great, but then when previewing on a regular device without the bottom controls there is an ugly space between the rest of the layout and the bottom. **I would like the margins between items to increase when there is available space.**

Pictures are added below. Sorry for the ugly cutting of some of the fields, I'm unable to show them at this time to due a contract. Notice how "advacned search" is far from the bottom, **I would like the vertical margins between all items to increase and make sure this doesnt happen.**

How can I acheive this in a relative layout?

[image: Nexus 4]

[image: Regular 4.7"]

Comment: Plz checkout Android's official tutorial: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html You can achieve your goal by putting `dimens.xml` in res folder corresponding to the screen size.

Comment: @IzzyLeung have looked it many times, the problem is the DP units dont scale properly between nexus devices and regular devices. While the margins should clearly grow since there is more space, they don't. Also, there is no way to create a seperate layout for nexus devices (or devices with virtual controls in general) since the screen density is the same as the regular device with the same screen...

Comment: Well, I think it's beyond my knowledge. Sorry about that.

Comment: What about using a relative layout in the end and putting the advanced search inside it and setting AlignParentBottom to true?

Comment: @JamsheedKamarudeen Thank you for your suggestion, Unfortunately I've already tried that and there would be just a lot of space somewhere else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using LinearLayout and empty Views between each of the items.
just empty View:

```
<View
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Comment: I don't know how to archive this in RelativeLayout.

Comment: Thanks, but I've asked for relative layout, as there are sometimes 2 items in a single row and using linear layout inside another is expensive

Comment: two nested linear-layouts are not so expensive and you can easily do this. don't worry about nesting in this case.

Comment: Oh well, thanks then. It's weird that Google, that push the use of virtual home & back don't provide a solution for relative layouts as well. Answer accepted